# Add in select of Hibernate criteria 'case ... when ... then ... end' as new field

Tags: java, sql, hibernate

I want add equivalent SQL in Hibernate criteria

```
SELECT
...
CASE
  WHEN a=1 then 2 
  WHEN a=2 then 3 
  WHEN a=3 then 0 
  WHEN a=4 then 1 
END as newfield
...
```

I buid big criteria and I don't whan rewrite in HQL

If I cann't add in Hibernate criteria (using criteria's methods),

maybe, I can add in criteria how part of the query (kind sql injection criteria)